# How to show a database row with my search button?

Tags: php

this is my search.php code. i am trying to search wherein the user will input the subscriber id and it will show the FirstName, LastName and address of the accepted SubscriberID

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
 <?php
 $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","kuyahajji","steve");
 if (isset($POST['submit-SubscriberID']))  {
    $choice = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['$SubscriberID']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM property WHERE SubscriberID='$choice'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $queryResult = mysqli_num-rows($result);
    if ($queryResult > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
            echo $result;
    }
    }
        else {
            echo "0 results";
    }
 } 
 ?>     

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have a separate form.php and its ok already

Comment: i got it now.. thanks u_mulder

Answer (score 0):

`$row` is **array**. To output required key use `[]` notation:

```
echo $row['FirstName'] . $row['LastName'];
```

Also correct name for a function is `mysqli_num_rows` (all underscores).

Comment: I have corrected - to _ and the echo statements.  It can get to my search.php from my form.php.  But, still  it wont show anything.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $_POST['SubscriberID'], without $?